# Assign NTA's to lat longs using R?

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, reverse-geocoding

I have lat longs and want R to return a column of the neighborhood tabulation area for each point;

lat           long           NTA
40.79127    -73.96484       Morningside Heights
40.72622    -73.98380       East Village
40.79196    -73.96809       Upper West Side

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an spatial join, after converting your lat-longs to a spatial object. This is done easily with package `sf`, replace the filenames with yours on the following code:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
lat_longs = read.csv(latlongs.csv) %>% 
     st_as_sf(coords = c("longitude_column", "latitude_column")) %>% 
     st_set_crs(4326) # coordinate reference system is lat-long
NTA = read_sf("nta_polygons.shp")

lat_longs_NTA = lat_longs %>% st_join(NTA)
```